# Nylas N1 sync-engine on Raspberry Pi

Tags: software-installation, server

Is there a streamlined way to install the Nylas N1 [sync-engine](https://github.com/nylas/sync-engine) mail server on a Pi, such as the Pi 3? I found some Debian installer but they appear to require a virtual machine and I don't know whether the Pi can handle it.

Answer (score 2):

I found [this tutorial](http://techblog.danielpellarini.com/sysadmin/how-to-install-the-nylas-sync-engine-on-ubuntu-server/) for those running Ubuntu derivatives:

> 1. `sudo apt-get update`
> 2. `sudo apt-get upgrade`
> 3. `sudo apt-get install libssl-dev` (should install with install script, but right now is bugged)
> 4. `git clone https://github.com/nylas/sync-engine.git`
> 5. `cd sync-engine`
> 6. `sudo -H ./setup.sh` (If you get a warning about upgrading to pip version 8.12 from a previous version, run `sudo -H pip install —upgrade pip` and then run the setup script again. The -H option is used to avoid pip from complaining that the user root is not the owner of the current cache directory in use.)
> 7. Launch the API service: `bin/inbox-api`
> 8. Launch the sync service: `bin/inbox-start`
> 9. Add your first email account: `bin/inbox-auth email@domain.com`
> 10. Connect from client by choosing “Hosting your own sync engine?” option on the N1 welcome screen. Enter your Sync Engine IP and use port 5555.

Comment: But it fails due to dependency issues when trying to install on ARM devices. https://github.com/nylas/sync-engine/issues/414

Comment: Yep—I actually filed that bug report. Hoping the dependency will be resolved soon